# Make a minimum player to join room Photon Pun 2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I want to ask how to create a room with a minimum player, for example if there is 1 player in the room then the player cannot start the game, if there are 2 players in the room then the game can start. I've tried searching on photon websites but only get Max Player. I try to search in the photon website but just max plyaer in there, can anyone help me.Please help.

This is My Code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using TMPro;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System.Linq;

public class Launcher : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{    
    public static Launcher Instance;
    [SerializeField] TMP_InputField roomNameInputField;
    [SerializeField] TMP_Text errorText;
    [SerializeField] TMP_Text roomNameText;
    [SerializeField] Transform roomListContent;
    [SerializeField] GameObject roomListItemPrefab;
    [SerializeField] GameObject PlayerListItemPrefab;
    [SerializeField] Transform playerListContent;
    [SerializeField] GameObject startGameButton;

    [SerializeField] private byte maxPlayersPerRoom = 4;

    void Awake(){
        Instance = this;
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Connecting to Master");
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
    }

    public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
        Debug.Log("Connected to Master");
        PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby();
        PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;
    }
     public override void OnJoinedLobby()
    {   
        MenuSetting.Instance.OpenMenu("firstmenu");
        Debug.Log("Joined Lobby");
    }
      public void CreateRoom(){
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(roomNameInputField.text)){
            return;
        }
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomNameInputField.text, new RoomOptions() {MaxPlayers = maxPlayersPerRoom}, null);
        MenuSetting.Instance.OpenMenu("Loading");
    }

    public override void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        MenuSetting.Instance.OpenMenu("room");
        roomNameText.text = PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.Name;

        Player[] players = PhotonNetwork.PlayerList;

        foreach(Transform child in playerListContent)
        {
            Destroy(child.gameObject);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < players.Count(); i++){
            Instantiate(PlayerListItemPrefab, playerListContent).GetComponent<PlayerListItem>().SetUp(players[i]);
        }

        
        startGameButton.SetActive(PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient);
    }

    public override void OnMasterClientSwitched(Player newMasterClient)
    {
        startGameButton.SetActive(PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient);
    }
    public override void OnCreateRoomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
    {
        errorText.text = "Room Creation Failed: " + message;
        MenuSetting.Instance.OpenMenu("error");
    }

    public void StartGame()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(1);
    }
    public void LeaveRoom()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom();
        MenuSetting.Instance.OpenMenu("main_menu");
    }

    public void JoinRoom(RoomInfo info){
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(info.Name);
        MenuSetting.Instance.OpenMenu("loading");
    }

    public override void OnLeftRoom()
    {
        MenuSetting.Instance.OpenMenu("loading");

    }

    public override void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> roomList)
    {
        foreach(Transform trans in roomListContent){
            Destroy(trans.gameObject);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < roomList.Count; i++){
            if(roomList[i].RemovedFromList)
                continue;
            Instantiate(roomListItemPrefab, roomListContent).GetComponent<RoomListItem>().SetUp(roomList[i]);
        }
    }

    public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
    {
        Instantiate(PlayerListItemPrefab, playerListContent).GetComponent<PlayerListItem>().SetUp(newPlayer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to check the player count in the OnJoinedRoom method.

Modify the OnJoinedRoom method to check the number of players in the room before allowing the game to start. Here's an example:

```
public override void OnJoinedRoom()
{
    MenuSetting.Instance.OpenMenu("room");
    roomNameText.text = PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.Name;

    Player[] players = PhotonNetwork.PlayerList; //get all the players

    foreach(Transform child in playerListContent)
    {
        Destroy(child.gameObject);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < players.Count(); i++){
        Instantiate(PlayerListItemPrefab, playerListContent).GetComponent<PlayerListItem>().SetUp(players[i]);
    }

    // Check the number of players in the room
    if (players.Count() >= 2)
    {
        startGameButton.SetActive(PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient); //only show the button if there are more than 2 players
    }
    else
    {
        startGameButton.SetActive(false); // hide the button if there are less than 2 players
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!